# Ошибка redis и celery в docker контейнере

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

Запущена очередь задач celery-beat совместно с redis. Redis начал постоянно выдавать ошибку:

```
Failed opening the RDB file root (in server root dir /etc) for saving: Permission denied
redis     | 1:M 16 Mar 2021 01:18:14.189 # Background saving error
```

Может кто сталкивался? Как лечить?

Comment: Когда видите в тексте ошибки `Permission denied`, должно становиться очевидным, что проблема с правами. В данном случае, сервис пытается сохранить какие то данные в директории, где его права ограничены. Все решается настройками и предоставлением правильного доступа. Видя Ваши файлы настроек, было бы проще разобраться.

Comment: Запускал redis без файла конфигурации, в этом была проблема. Добавил конфиг и прописал в нем параметр dir, ошибка пропала.